# waiting two seconds then auto redirect another page in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the html structure:

```
<div class="user_register border_y">
<div>
<span style="color:green;"> after  two seconds then auto redirect </span><br><br> 

<a href="http://example.com/down/test.html">if you don't want to wait you can click this。</a></div></div>
```

i want to use jquery to get: after  two seconds then auto redirect to the `a` label page. how should i do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't even need jQuery; vanilla JS will work fine...

```
<a id="link" href="http://example.com">Go NOW!!!</a>
```

JS:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
location.href = document.getElementsByClassName("user_register border_y")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
}, 2000);
```

`getElementsByClassName` doesn't work in all browsers; so make sure you provide a [fallback](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldom08.htm)

Comment: setInterval is not the right way to do this.  You want a one-shot timer, not a repeating timer which would be setTimeout, not setInterval.

Comment: As elegant as jQuery is, I'm a big fan of not introducing it unless it's a page that heavily requires it (i.e. lots of scripted actions / events). However, I would suggest setTimeout instead.

Comment: You're right; I'd heard something about setTimeout being bad but I'm thinking it was hogwash. Updated.

Comment: if i can't add a class or an ID to the a label and there are many a lable in the page out the div. how should i do?

Comment: @zhuanzhou see udpated answer

Comment: i am sorry, it shows an error document.getElementsByClassName("user_register border_y").getElementsByTagName is not a function

Comment: @zhuanzhou did you even implement the getElementsByClassName fallback like I mentioned?

Comment: i put your code in a js file. it can't work in FF. then i put the code in firebug console.it shows the above's error.

Comment: Thomas: You can't call `getElementsByTagName` directly from the collection returned by `getElementsByClassName`. You need to pull a DOM element out first.

Comment: @patrick yup, just realized I hadn't put that in. Stupid me. :)

Answer (score 16):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    window.location.href = $("a")[0].href; 
 }, 2000);
```

Comment: karim79,could you tell me why using 2000 not 2. because it's two seconds

Comment: @zhuanzhou - `setTimeout` expects the argument to be in milliseconds, and 2000 milliseconds == 2 seconds.

Answer (score 11):

Why use JavaScript?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://example.com/down/test.html">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="user_register border_y">
    <div>
    <span style="color:green;"> after  two seconds then auto redirect </span><br><br> 

    <a href="http://example.com/down/test.html">if you don't want to wait you can click this。</a></div></div>
```

Comment: i am sorry, the page is dynamic

Comment: `meta refresh` is not reliable, e.g. in IE I can turn it off.

Comment: @Mrchief: Well you can turn off JavaScript as well. ;o)

Comment: yeah but its not off by default. further, you cannot live with js turned off whereas this setting - no one cares!

Answer (score 4):

Below is a simple script based off of your description:

```
function redirect(){
   window.location = $('a').attr('href');
}

setTimeout(redirect, 2000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KesU9/

Comment: I edited your code to read `setTimeout(redirect, 2000)`. The previous code had `redirect()` which would have run the redirect function as soon as the timeout was set, instead of simply assigning redirect to the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple code on **body OnLoad**

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout(location.href='http://www.newpage.com', '2000')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to redirect. 
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var time = 15; // Time coutdown
var page = "http://www.redirect-url.com/";
function countDown(){
time--;
gett("timecount").innerHTML = time;
if(time == -1){
window.location = page;
}
}
function gett(id){
if(document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(id);
if(document.all) return document.all.id;
if(document.layers) return document.layers.id;
if(window.opera) return window.opera.id;
}
function init(){
if(gett('timecount')){
setInterval(countDown, 1000);
gett("timecount").innerHTML = time;
}
else{
setTimeout(init, 50);
}
}
document.onload = init();
</SCRIPT>
```

add this code after body tab

```
<h3>Auto redirect after <span id="timecount"></span> second(s)!</h3>
```